# CSS: Keep DT and DD together within columns

Tags: css

I have a definition list split in multiple columns:

```
dl { -webkit-column-count: 2; }
```

Unfortunately, I sometimes have a case where a `DT` occurs at the very bottom of one column and its following `DD` at the top of the next, which looks really ugly. Since I can't wrap the elements I want to keep together in a container, my only option appears to be something like:

```
dt { -webkit-column-break-after: avoid; }
```

but that doesn't seem to work. Any ideas?

[Here's a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nc3mfbww/) that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: (obviously, it would be nice to get this working across all browsers, but Chrome is required, so I'm starting there)

Comment: Got a demo for us? It might make it easier to play if we had some code to deal with.

Comment: @Paulie_D: Give me a few minutes and I'll try to put something together

Comment: @Paulie_D fiddle added

Comment: Hmmm...without wrapping up the `dt/dd` I think you will have trouble here.

Comment: If you wrap each pair of {`dt`,`dd`} in a `div`, then apply `-webkit-column-break-inside:avoid` to that div, you get a result that at least does something... but it might not really be what you want. It seems that `-webkit-column-break-after` is ignored by Chrome (according to http://help.dottoro.com/lcrthhhv.php).

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/nc3mfbww/3/

Comment: @Paulie_D has come up with exactly the same thing. The downside is that column breaks can't happen even within long `dd` blocks.

Comment: Yeah, that's certainly an option, guys. I've done something similar before whereby I do the wrapping using javascript so, whilst it doesn't work for everyone, it does at least keep the markup cleaner. I think the disadvantage that Chris points out might be a deal-breaker, though - at least I can run it past my designer. It's so frustrating that css columns still aren't properly supported, even by ostensibly good browser manufacturers like Google!

Comment: Well, they are pretty well suppported but there are specific implementations that are, perhaps, not best suited to a column layout. Plus...they're new so not everything works out of the gate,